# Why is vue store state defined differently? (Nuxt, vue)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

```
// nuxt vuex module
export const state = () => ({
  test : '',
});

// state should be a method that returns an object in store/index.js 
export const state = {
  test : '',
};
```

```
// pure vue or classic mode
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0
  },
})
```

Why do we need to return state to a function in nuxt when using vuex in module mode?

I don't know why.

In the case of mutations and actions, if you assign an object right away, is it normal to assign the state as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question, I wasn't sure about this either. The only thing I could find is [this comment](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/754#issuecomment-358591042). Apparently it is to work around concurrency problems, something Vue wouldn't experience in the browser.

> For example, about returning a function for the state in the store files, it's actually Evan who implemented it into Nuxt.js to avoid having the same state between 2 concurrent requests

**Edit**

Following the rabbit hole a bit more, the broader picture is that it's needed to adhere to this server-rendering rule: ["Avoid Stateful Singletons"](https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/structure.html#avoid-stateful-singletons)

The node side of things needs a way to get a fresh copy of initial state, which is only possible with a function since the state object could have been mutated by some other request.

Comment: Node side is single-threaded, do you mean you need a state object returned by a function?

As you read the vue ssr guide, why are you returning a function to create a singleton state for each request?

In the case of CSR mode, it is understood that execution context is created based on single thread, so it is not necessary to return to the function.

Comment: @zero86 concurrency in this context isn't related to number of threads. It's about getting a fresh representation of state for new requests. If you express this as an object literal, you would open the door to bugs caused by some other request mutating that object

Comment: Would it help to understand the concept of immutable objects?
Thank you for answer
@Matt

Comment: @zero86 not in this case, because the server code may actually want to mutate the state for an individual request (e.g. inflating a user session in [nuxtServerInit](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/vuex-store/#the-nuxtserverinit-action)). This mutation may be irrelevant (e.g. a different user ID) for another request on the same node, which is why nuxt needs a function that returns a fresh copy of initial state

Comment: Do you understand that for each request, to ensure that the singleton receives a guaranteed state object and then processes it for each request? @Matt

Comment: I don't understand much yet. It only makes sense to ensure that the state object fits each request. @Matt